# How to map list using value from another list 1 by 1 in Elixir?

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

Suppose I have a Player Struct inside list

```elixir
[
  %Player{name: "John", role: "nil"},
  %Player{name: "Sansa", role: "nil"},
  %Player{name: "Barry", role: "nil"},
  %Player{name: "Edward", role: "nil"}
]
```

and I have a list of roles:

```elixir
 Enum.shuffle([:werewolf, :farmer, :farmer, :farmer])
```

What function to use || How do I map it one by one into my expected result:

```elixir
[
  %Player{name: "John", role: ":farmer"},
  %Player{name: "Sansa", role: ":farmer"},
  %Player{name: "Barry", role: ":werewolf"},
  %Player{name: "Edward", role: ":farmer"}
]
```

I tried mapping, but with OO background, all I think is matching the index, which is not efficient in Elixir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when you want to somehow work with two lists on the same size and do something element-wise, [`Enum.zip/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#zip/2) or [`Enum.zip_with/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#zip_with/3) are a common and efficient way to achieve it without relying on index access.

Your example can be solved by:

```elixir
Enum.zip_with(players, roles, fn player, role -> Map.put(player, :role, role) end)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have missed zip documentation. That was fast thank you! Mind telling how do you remember all the function?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the best way for me was probably to keep a tab with the `Enum` module open and spend some time looking for what exists in there whenever facing a "loop" problem. At first you might spend some time reading through functions that don't do exactly what you need, but as you get more familiar with the various functions you should soon find yourself checking the docs less and less.
Maybe a cheatsheet could help here as well? (I just found [this one](https://angelika.me/elixir-enum-cheatsheet/), it seems nice and quite visual)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a different approach: make them all farmers, and randomly assign one as the warewolf:

```elixir
defmodule Player do
  defstruct name: nil, role: :farmer

  def setup do
    [werewolf | farmers] =
      ["John", "Sansa", "Barry", "Edward"]
      |> Enum.map(fn name -> %Player{name: name} end)
      |> Enum.shuffle()

    [%Player{werewolf | role: :werewolf} | farmers]
  end
end
```

This will return the players in a random order, though (and the werewolf will always be first).

Comment: Interesting alternative! Another idea that keeps the order but re-uses the "randomly assign one" concept:
```language-elixir
werewolf_index = Enum.random(1..length(players)) - 1
Enum.with_index(players, fn 
  player, ^werewolf_index -> Map.put(player, :role, :werewolf)
  player, _ -> player
end)
```

Comment: yes, sorry my question wasn't clear. there can be more than 4 players, which mean there can be more than one werewolf:  Enum.shuffle([:werewolf, :seer, :werewolf, :farmer, :harlot, :farmer])

Comment: I see, maybe it could be adapted with something like `werewolf_indexes = Enum.take_random(1..length(players), werewolf_count)` and `if index in werewolf_indexes, do: :werewolf, else: :farmer`